# passing username and password to the server in a secure way

Tags: asp.net, security

In my web application there is a sign up page with five `textbox`  (username, password,confirm password,email and confirm email) , and a `button` named register . As i know a wise suggestion is to hash the password before save in `database` , but hashing the password is done in server side . The password is sending to server (from client side) without any change.

**My first question** : is there any possibility to access this unchanged password with hackers?
**Second question** : if the answer is yes , is there any way to send password to server without this risk?

Comment: use https. plain and simple.

Comment: You should read Peter Gutmann's *[Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf)* before you go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just use HTTPS.
[Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

In `Startup.cs`, use `UseHttpsRedirection`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The following code calls AddHttpsRedirection to configure middleware options:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
        options.Preload = true;
        options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
        options.ExcludedHosts.Add("example.com");
        options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.example.com");
    });

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 5001;
    });            
}
```

Comment: Thanks , perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

This is what https/tls (formerly ssl) is for.

You need to ensure that the login page can *only* be accessed via https. Any http-only requests should be rejected or forwarded to the https page. Additionally, once you have a issued a login token, whatever form that takes, all pages that use that token should only be allowed to use https.

You can write code for this, but generally I find it easier to handle this at the web server (IIS) level.

Comment: Thanks , very useful